# How to run UglifyJS2 without Node.JS

Tags: javascript, jvm, scriptengine, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Anyway to run [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) without node.js? Say I would like to run it in a JVM process using JavaScript script engine. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I saw mishoo answered you
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/122

Two possible ways:

- run `uglifyjs --self` to get a build of UglifyJS that you can load in a browser (or in any JS environment) and you can use the API [described here](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/).
- load in your environment all files in the lib/ directory (load `utils.js` and `ast.js` first, the others can come in whatever order). If you do this, everything will be global—you can use the same API but there's no need to prefix stuff with UglifyJS..

Also you might want to look at `tools/node.js` to see how we load it in Node (as we're not using the standard `require`).