# UglifyJS2 without Node?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs2

I have a need for compressing JavaScript in a PHP environment. System calls are okay, but I'm working in PHP.

I don't want to have to download and install NodeJS *just* to get access to Uglify, but Uglify seems to be the only reliable* minifier.

Can anyone point me to how this can be done, or if not are there any other good minifiers/manglers?

<sub>* Closure Compiler somehow manages to return *bigger* files due to being overzealous with putting string contants into the places they are used</sub>

Comment: Regarding your Closure Compiler note, does it actually result in a larger gzipped result? In my experience, those sorts of variable substitutes for constants don't pay off at all when gzipping.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case it resulted in a 3% bigger gzipped file compared to the original gzipped size.

Comment: Have you tried YUI compressor? It runs on the JVM as well.

Comment: Well, sort of. I can't seem to find a download of the right thing. I've tried all the download links but none of them actually contain the compressor...

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be much help there. I've only used some of the online versions, [like this](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/). For the most part I've either used Closure Compiler or Uglify.

Comment: use curl to emulate a post to http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764529/how-to-run-uglifyjs2-without-node-js